# Authentication Failed when trying to upload document using Fedex api

Tags: java, php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to upload a "commercial invoice" for FedEx using their UploadDocument Api. But I always get the error

> {"Severity"=>"ERROR", "Source"=>"prof", "Code"=>"1000", "Message"=>"Authentication Failed"}"

Although I used the same `credentials` and create a successful Shipment? Could you help me resolve this issue?